# How best to include files like css and javascript, when you have multiple level folders?

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, directory, directory-structure

First, I've always done my sites, with every file in the root folder. Because of that, I've never had to do a different, if only slightly, path to my css and includes.

Having read a bit into SEO though, I found that it can be helpful to have several folders helping to describe, with keywords, where you are at.

So, say I have a folder as such.

(root)
Index.php
(root/memories/)
index.php
(root/memories/dreams/)
index.php

These 3 index files, will have different paths to my css and includes folder.

The question explained then is.
What is the easiest and/or best way to link to these files, which are going to have different paths depending on what file your in.

Hope I explained it well enough, my 1st question on here.

P.S. I'm working offline. localhost.

Answer (score 2):

You can link your files using something like /root/memories/yourcss.css , /root/memories/dreams/yourcss.css

Comment: I know.. but as the site gets bigger that would get rather troublesome I' imagine. was hoping for a better way. do you know if this is the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Just use positive location

```
<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/css/location/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, say if I am in a sub folder already, and want to go up to level 1 folder (HOME)

Comment: Damn it! okay.. so if you hit enter it sends.. alright
Whenever I do what you've said, and add the whole location as the link, it simply adds that.. ontop of the directory I'm already in.

Comment: So, If I'm at. 
site/memories/dreams
Clicks on Home, which takes me to site/
then my location becomes
site/memories/dreams/site
It simply adds it to where I'm already at.

P.S. I'm working in localhost.

Comment: No.. 
No links work, for main menu.
say I wanna go from home to blog, and them from blog to home.
My directory looks like this: 
localhost/mysite/myblog/blog.php/localhost/mysite/index.php
which obviously doesn't exist.. it adds it ontop of rather then rewrites the original link.

Comment: So far, the only way I can get the css to work on the blog site. is to do this to the link
"../../../site/css/stylesheet.css"
Which, with more sub sides to come and with images reappearing on multiple pages with links of their own.. just doesn't seem right in my head.

Comment: with it being on localhost it does become a problem to trouble shoot because of the server settings can you do <?= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/location/script.css';?> as the location in the css include

Comment: also the reason localhost/maindirectory/css/location/style.css did not work is because you need a http:// before the localhost. I tryed to add it in the comment but it just made it a link and removed it.

Comment: Alright, with that. I've gotten it to link, my css that is, to the exact location. However still no layout changes, it is not in effect.

Comment: Nothing yet, sorry.
And if I take the link which we've created and paste it into the browser, it shows my .css and its contents, proving that its the correct path.